# Deleting a row in a UITableViewController with an alert confirmation

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have an `UITableViewController`, set up so that users can delete rows. This is my code for the handler of the delete action, and the delegate method for the `UIAlertView`:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"t" message:@"del?" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Delete", nil];
        [alert show];
    }
}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    NSIndexPath *path = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    if (buttonIndex != [alertView cancelButtonIndex]) {
        //my code to delete from the data source is here. it works fine.
        [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:path] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }
}
```

The problem is in that last line where it's supposed to actually delete the rows from the `tableView`. If I put that (and the code that deletes from the data source) in the first method instead of the `UIAlertView` stuff, it works fine.

What is the proper way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the `UIIndexPath` object was wrong inside that method! I guess it's because there is no row selected while the alert view is showing. So, I saved it before doing the `UIAlertView` code into a property of the view controller class, and retrieved it later in the second method, and it works fine.